# Display confirmation message after post with RedirectToAction and without TempData

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post-redirect-get

I have a problem with something apparently simple, however all of the answers I find in SO and Google are not applicable.

I am creating an MVC page for an existing system, which requires:

- the initial Get method to pass two parameters (that enables the 'context' of the page) - `jobId` and `parentId`.
- session state is disabled, therefore `TempData` is not an option.

So, I have an Index() method which builds a model based on the two parameters and data from DB.

```
 public ActionResult Index(int jobId, int? parentId = null)
    {
        //build model based on Id params
        var model = new JobModel
        {
            ...
        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

The view has got several forms on it that allow some actions to be carried out on the model (add files, remove files)

```
         @using (Html.BeginForm("AddNewFiles", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.JobId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ParentId)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AdditionalFiles, new {type = "file", multiple = "true"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AdditionalFiles)
            <input type="submit" name="SubmitNewFiles" id="SubmitNewFiles" value="Upload"/>
        }
```

Submission of this form moves me to the proper Post action

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddNewFiles(JobModel jobModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            throw new InvalidDataException(message: "Model is invalid");
        }
        //doing some stuff with the files here
        //...

        //now I want to get back to the initial page with forms etc, however show a temporary label somewhere saying that 'something happened OK'
        return RedirectToAction("Index", routeValues: new RouteValueDictionary(values: new
        {
            jobId = job.Id,
            parentId = job.OrganizationId
        }));
    }
```

Now, the problem is that I don't know how can I show a message on the page.
As I said, I cannot use `TempData` (which is 50% suggested answers).

Other solutions include `return View("Index")` instead of `return RedirectToAction("Index")` - however in this case I don't know how could I pass the proper parameters for my `Index(int jobId, int? parentId = null)` method, so that the updated model can be generated.

I am just beginning with MVC so I suppose the answer is pretty simple, however all the things I found are not applicable in my case I think. Cheers!

Comment: You could always just add another parameter `string message` to your `Index()` method and pass it in the `routeValues`

Comment: I was thinking about it... but - I will have approx. 5 forms, each of which should display a different message, therefore I wanted the messages to appear in different places (above each respective form). Also, if I add it to routeValues, it would appear in the link, correct? (I don't want that to happen)

Comment: Then you have no choice but to persist it somewhere (e.g. database). But why do you have 5 forms in the view - that suggest an problem with your design

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Maybe there is a problem with design... The page displays details of a Job object. I have multiple separate forms because there will be multiple actions that can be carried out on the Job - 1) Add files, 2) Remove files, 3) Add users, 4) Add languages, 5) Remove languages etc. Each of these should appear in a separate section of the page, with separate 'Submit your changes' button

Comment: I thought perhaps a cookie would be a solution. but not sure how to handle it (and whether its good usage of cookies)?

Comment: So why not just one form where you can edit everything associated with `JobModel`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Because I want the users to have a clear distinction of what they are editing and submitting, hence separate submit buttons. In any case, would having just one form change much in my case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111278/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-bartosz).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using TempData you have a couple of options:

- Supply the message via QueryString, where you don't even need to change your target controller action, you can just capture the value using Request.QueryString["key"] - if you wish to keep the target action as is
- Store a temporary cookie that you eliminate on the target action (sounds a bit overkill but it is an option)
- If you do not want to pass the message in plain text you can use (via QS for eg) an id for a message you have on a Lookup or Dictionary or even your underlying storage system and just use that undecipherable id on the target action to retrieve the message and send it to the view

Once you have the message or the id on the target action you can use ViewBag, ViewData or the Model itself to provide that info to the view.

Answer (score 0):

2 ways you could do it:

**ViewBag** Use the `ViewBag` dynamic object to set a message in. E.g. in your Controller where you want to set the message: `ViewBag.EnterANameForYourMessage = "your message string here";`

The ViewBag gets passed between the Controller and View and is a dynamic object where you can add any property names with any type. It *is* however, advised that you know exactly what these types are when you are using/parsing them out again.

Then on your View, check if the `ViewBag.EnterANameForYourMessage' object is not null (or use '!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()' method). Display the value in a div if it is not.

*OR*

**Model** Add some sort of "message" `string` property to the object being passed between the Controller/View.

Where you parse the message out, add your string to the "message" property.

Then, return the model to the view as before.

I'm doing this in-app so the methods I'm on about might be a little off (its early and I can't remember exact names off the top of my head).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Geoff - As for ViewBag, it is cleared when you use RedirectToAction, so this would not work... As for message in the Model, I am not sure I like this idea (after all, 'confirmation message' or whatever is not really a part of the Job object)

Comment: Good point with the ViewBag @Bartosz. And I agree; using a message in the model would be out of scope of what the Job object's designed for. Another suggestion would be to allow the `Index()` action to also take a `string? message = null` as an argument, and then use it in the ViewBag (as I suggested) - passing the `message = "xyz";` into your `new RouteValueDictionary`.

Comment: Then the message would appear in the URL I think, which also seems kind of wrong:(

Comment: This is true. It depends how secret (or not) you want the message to be, and if you need it to be variable from your controller sending it. Alternatively you could send something for the other View to check for in the query string. e.g. `success = "y" and then show a message in the View if this is present.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect with parameter,

```
return RedirectToAction("Action", new { id = 10});
```

Handle parameter in ActionResult and set model's message.

```
public ActionResult Action(int id)
        {
          if(id == 10)
            {
               Model.Message = "Success";
            }
            return View(Model);
        }
```

Model,

```
 public class ViewModel
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
```

Then show it in View.
In View

```
<p> @Model.Message </p>
```